# Extracting Data from a list- find the highest value

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a `table` and set it as a data frame. The first four variables are factors while the last four (fare, tax, comm, net) are numbers. I need to find which TA (travel agent) has sold the most tickets. How can I print the name along the max result? ex: 3300 ,pay more. In addition, in this table I have two variables (3300 and 3303) with the highest ticket amount (4)  Is R choose the first highest variable?. Can I present all results? meaning: 3300 pay more 4   3303 pay by ticket 4.

[image: Example table]

Comment: For future reference, posting an image of data is all but useless - copy and paste the actual values as text, or even better use `dput(tablename)` to spit out a representation of your data.

Comment: -1 I cannot understand what you are asking for. One example: 3300 and 3303 are values and not variables. Also you do not use the column names from your table but some other words.

Comment: I need to find which travel agent (IATA number and name) sold the most tickets. after finding that I need R to print the IATA numbers and the travel agent names that sold the highest amount of tickets. In this case IATA 3300 and 3303. I enter the IATAs as factors and not as numbers. The answer below give the first highest result and not all the results in the table. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `IATA` is the ticket agent variable:

```
df = data.frame(IATA=c(3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3301, 3301, 3302, 3303, 3303))
table(df$IATA)
# 3300 3301 3302 3303 
#    4    2    1    2
```

As you can see, `table` gives the frequency of ticket sales by each ticket agent.

```
names(which.max(table(df$IATA)))
# [1] "3300"
```

If there are ties and you need all of them, try:

```
df = data.frame(IATA=c(3300, 3300, 3300, 3300, 3301, 3301, 3302, 3303, 3303, 3303, 3303))
names(which(table(df$IATA) == max(table(df$IATA))))
# [1] "3300" "3303"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Is the variables structure is crucial in such a case?

Comment: No, this should work on factor variables as well as non-factor variables.

Comment: Thanks, if i created a DF with both the IATA and the name how can I print the name along the max result? ex: 3300 ,pay more. In addition, in this table I have two variables (3300 and 3303) with the highest ticket amount however R chose the first one. can I present all results?

Comment: @EP_NYC I edited the response to handle a non-unique maximum. If you want the associated `NAME` variable, you could just run the code on that variable instead of `IATA`.

Comment: Thank you. So it is not possible to get all the results together? I need to run one function for IATA and then again the same one for NAME?

Comment: Try running the function on `paste(df$IATA, df$NAME)`.